# how to disable displaying time in datatype smalldatetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, types, smalldatetime

I have a textbox that should inserting a date in dd/MM/yyyy format. What only I can find and use is smalldatetime or datetime. I pick smalldatetime and the data displayed was like for example 01/07/2011 12:00:00 AM. Any codes involved to sort this out to be only displaying 01/07/2011 (without time)?

SqlJobMaster.InsertParameters["StartDate"].DefaultValue = txtStartDate.Text.ToString();

ASP.NET

Start Date

Comment: What's displaying the data? You've only talked about how you're inserting it into the database, which isn't where the problem is...

Comment: @Jon Skeet 01/07/2011 12:00:00 AM it displayecd like that in my gridView.

Comment: Have you checked `ToShortDateString()` ? try using this on the DateTime object you have

Comment: @Commando: Right, so it's the grid view which needs changing, in terms of what format it's using...

Answer (score 2):

use `ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`. Then it will get formatted the way you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used `GridView` in ASP.NET, but according to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx) you basically need to set the [`DataFormatString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) property for the relevant `BoundField`, e.g. to `"{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"`. You should consider cultural variations though, if your app is to be used in multiple cultures: `"{0:d}"` is the general "short date pattern for the current culture" format string.

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt);
```

Comment: where to put this? mine  DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text);
            SqlJobMaster.InsertParameters["StartDate"].DefaultValue = dt.ToShortDateString(); still not working

Comment: `string s = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt);` this is just when you want to display it... if you store it into your database there is no need to do such things

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text);
SqlJobMaster.InsertParameters["StartDate"].DefaultValue = dt.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: DateTime dt = txtStartDate.Text;  when I declare this, it showing cannot implicitly convert type'string' to 'System.DateTime'

Comment: sorry... DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text)

Comment: still not working.Still displaying the time. here's my code  DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text);
            SqlJobMaster.InsertParameters["StartDate"].DefaultValue = dt.ToShortDateString();